# Не работает цикл, если в нём нажимается левая кнопка мыши

Tags: c#

Из-за строчки `mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN | MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, x, y, 0, 0);` не выполняется цикл, что делать?

Вот весь код:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern void mouse_event(int dwFlags, int dx, int dy, int dwData, int dwExtraInfo);

private const int MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE = 0x0001;
private const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = 0x0002;
private const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = 0x0004;
private const int MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN = 0x0008;
private const int MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP = 0x0010;
private const int MOUSEEVENTF_MIDDLEDOWN = 0x0020;
private const int MOUSEEVENTF_MIDDLEUP = 0x0040;
private const int MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE = 0x8000;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int i = 1;
    int x = 945;
    int y = 250;
    while(i < 10)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("");
        i++;
        Cursor.Position = new Point(x,y);
        y = y + 20;
        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN | MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, x, y, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: убрать эту строчку?

Comment: Что значит "не выполняется"? У меня выполняется, например.

Comment: эм... у меня нескромный вопрос, а зачем для обработки клика мышью в WinForms дергать WinAPI напрямую? Чем вас MouseClick() обидел?